# Hardcoded values in composite foreign keys in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a `PARTNER` table with two primary keys:

```
CREATE TABLE PARTNER (
    PARTNER_TYPE nvarchar(2) -- Primary key
    PARTNER nvarchar(10)     -- Primary key
    NAME nvarchar(25)
)
```

I also have a `LOCATION` table that references two partners. These partners are of different types (`Client` and `Employee`), meaning that I need to add two columns for the partner types:

```
CREATE TABLE LOCATION (
    LOCATION_ID int
    PARTNER_TYPE1 nvarchar(2) -- This is always CL for client, can I hardcode this?
    CLIENT nvarchar(10)
    PARTNER_TYPE2 nvarchar(2) -- This is always EM for employee, can I hardcode this?
    EMPLOYEE nvarchar(10)
```

I know I can set default values to the partner type columns above. But I am wondering if there is any way to "hardcode" these default values when creating the foreign keys, so I can avoid having those two partner type columns. Much appreciated.

Comment: Just as a side-note: you don't have two primary keys - you have **one** primary key, composed of **two columns**. By definition, a table can only ever have **one primary key** (or none) - but it cannot ever have more than one primary key.

Comment: Thank you @marc_s, to be honest I wrote it in a hurry but yes, I didn't use the right wording. I appreciate your note.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use persisted computed columns for the type fields in `LOCATION`.

[Computed Columns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

```
CREATE TABLE PARTNER (
    PARTNER_TYPE nvarchar(2) CHECK(PARTNER_TYPE IN (N'CL', N'EM')),
    PARTNER nvarchar(10),
    NAME nvarchar(25),
    PRIMARY KEY (PARTNER_TYPE, PARTNER)
)

CREATE TABLE LOCATION (
    LOCATION_ID int,
    PARTNER_TYPE1 AS N'CL' PERSISTED,
    CLIENT nvarchar(10),
    PARTNER_TYPE2 AS N'EM' PERSISTED,
    EMPLOYEE nvarchar(10),
    PRIMARY KEY (LOCATION_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (PARTNER_TYPE1, CLIENT) REFERENCES PARTNER(PARTNER_TYPE, PARTNER),
    FOREIGN KEY (PARTNER_TYPE2, EMPLOYEE) REFERENCES PARTNER(PARTNER_TYPE, PARTNER)
)
```

Comment: This was very insightful, thank you! I am just wondering if there is any feature to prevent adding those extra columns, even as computed. To be honest, I did a thorough research and I didn't find such a feature, but my client works with SAP/Oracle which apparently does let you hardcode values in foreign keys, so they want me to be completely certain of the lack of such feature. I appreciate your help again.

Comment: @BrunoLigutti That is not possible in SQL Server as far as I know. Have you considered using two tables instead? One for clients and another for employees.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help - there are about 10 partner types, so that would bloat the model. At the end I added a surrogate identity key to the partner table, and added a unique constraint on the two columns. Then, I used that key in the relationships. I really appreciate it, many thanks.